# How to convert datagridview (not datasource) to datatable without loop?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

I add rows datagridview one by one in button_click event, i add with :

```
Dgv.Rows.Add()
```

Now i need convert Dgv to datatable without loop, is it possible?

I using vb.net in visual studio 2012,

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use a DataTable as the DataSource of your DataGridView in the first place? -- What kind of requirement is this: *without loop*?

Comment: @Jimi          I'm updating the application, if the data source is changed from the datatable, it will be very inconvenient

Comment: Why? Can't you change `Dgv.Rows.Add()` in `[DataTable].Rows.Add()` in the procedure that adds those rows? What about my second question?

Comment: *"if the data source is changed from the datatable"*. Huh? Is the `DataSource` already set to a `DataTable`? Do you actually mean it would be inconvenient to change it TO a `DataTable`?

Comment: *"i need convert Dgv to datatable without loop"*. Firstly, there's no conversion. You need to create a `DataTable`, add the appropriate columns, then read the data from the grid and populate the `DataTable`. Secondly, the code you write won't necessarily have to include an explicit loop, there's still going to be looping going in behind the scenes. You could use a LINQ query to get the data and then perhaps a `ForEach` method to populate the table but you're making the code less efficient and harder to read while still having looping occurring in the called methods.

Comment: Why exactly is it inconvenient to bind a `DataTable`? Other than creating it and binding it, you might not even have to do anything else, although you probably should.

Comment: @IwanKurniawan you're trying to drive a nail backwards. That's not how either grids or datatables work. A grid isn't a data container. A grid binds to a datatable, not the other way around. That's how ADO.NET and Winforms are designed.

Answer (score 0):

Use a DataTable to populate your DGV, then it's easy to retrieve the data into a new DataTable as you need.

Example:

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable.Columns.Add("id");
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Name");
        dataTable.Columns.Add("address");
        dataTable.Columns.Add("phone");


        DataRow row = dataTable.NewRow();
        row["id"] = 1;
        row["name"] = "test1";
        row["address"] = "a";
        row["phone"] = 1;

        dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
```

To retrieve the data, changed or not, from the grid:

```
DataTable dataTableDGV = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;
```

Answer (score -3):

there!
You can try this:

```
Private Sub SurroundingSub()
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()

    For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In dgv.Columns
        dt.Columns.Add(col.Name)
    Next

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows
        Dim dRow As DataRow = dt.NewRow()

        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
            dRow(cell.ColumnIndex) = cell.Value
        Next

        dt.Rows.Add(dRow)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This covers up the bad code, it doesn't fix the problem. Datagrids aren't containers. They bind to datatables, not the other way around. A grid doesn't have enough information to recreate the datatable it was created from

Comment: This misses `without loop` by miles.